# What is best way to load either Rectangle(drawn by code) or Image in Qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a Qml file with one 'Rectangle' and an 'Image'. I want to load either one based on the property set in my.cpp file.

Please help me to find a best way to do this.

Actually I could think two possible ways to do the same:
1)      First approach is to have both the element (the image and rectangle), defined in the respective QML, and to control their visibility from my.cpp file. I can have a property, this property can control the visibility of either of the two. Drawback in this approach is that even though only one element has to be displayed, two will be created.

2)      Second approach is that we can have two components and load either one using "Loader" depending on the property set from the my.cpp.

Ex:

'
    Component
    {
        id:img
        Image
        {
            id: myImage
            source:currentdir + "/img_production/Separator/myImage.png"
            width: 10
            height: 79
        }
    }

```
Component
{
    id:rect
    Rectangle
    {
        id:re
        height: 82
        width: 10
        color: "#FFFFFF"
    }
}
Loader
{
    id: itemDisplay
    sourceComponent: style.flag? rect : img
    anchors.fill: parent.fill
}
```

'
Looking for some expert suggestions.

PS: style.flag is property set by my.cpp to Qml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, where both items are simple base types, I would go for the visibility change.

Having both elements instantiated directly makes it easier to refer to them in bindings or bind to their properties.
It also means their allocation only happens once, reducing the chance of memory fragmentation

If you are worried about the image consuming too much memory while the rectangle is shown you could still make the image`s source property depend in the visiblity value, i.e. unload the image when not showing the Image element.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I will try your suggestion. It seems easy to implement as well.

However, i want to understand here what if I choose using loader instead visibility change. I mean  why visibility change approach is better than having loader in Qml? I am new learner of Qml. Please pardon me for asking such a basic (..ok silly) question.

And just for my curiosity, I would like to know the other possible methods to solve my problem, if you have any.

Comment: The Loader is more complicated to handle since you don't have access to the loaded item in the same way you would with directly instantiated ones.
E.g. there is no id, no "scope" brackets into which you would write property bindings or signal handlers.
The Loader approach has the advantage, that it allows deferred/on-deman loading, which can speed up initial start time and control memory need.
In your case the latter doesn't matter much, since the Loader itself is an element and you would be loading another, i.e. two in total, the same you would have with visibilty change

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin.